# Laravel One to one relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get Store details,  belong to a specific user in blade template

getting this error:

```
 "ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"
```

I can get all details in User table, error comes when i am trying to get store table data.

```
@forelse ($users as  $user)
<span class="col-span-1 px-2 py-1 border">{{ $user->store->name }} </span> 
@endforeach
```

**User Model**

```
public function store()
{
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\store');
}
```

**store Model**

```
public function user()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User' );
}
```

Comment: what is the function name in User model?

Comment: Hi `@forelse` close with `@endforelse` not `@endforeach` you have mixed _forelse_ and _foreach_

Comment: You're right @sta but in the case, it should start with `@foreach` as no `@empty` was called. What I don't get is why blade didn't crash on the mix of 2 different tags.

Comment: `@forelse ($users as  $user)
        <span class="col-span-1 px-2 py-1 border"><a href="#">{{ $loop->iteration  }}. {{ $user->name }}</a></span>
        <span class="col-span-1 px-2 py-1 border">{{ $user->email }}</span>
        <span class="col-span-1 px-2 py-1 border">{{ $user->created_at->toDateString()  }}</span>
        <span class="col-span-1 px-2 py-1 border">
            {{-- {{ $user->store->name }} --}}
         </span>

        @empty
        <p class="col-span-4">No stores found...!</p>
        @endforelse`  I am using this code. but same result

Comment: is it store or Store? check the model name in relation

Comment: and if store is nullable then you can use something like {{ $user->store->name or 'N/A'}} to show N/A if store not found

Comment: it is store,  it works when I am using `Auth::user()->store->name ` in other pages

Answer (score -1):

It works when i added below code to the livewire component class

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`